# turtlebot bad gyro calibration

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rostopic echo  /diagnostics :

**we see a lot of '0's here. This may be a proble of my gear wheel. Thank you helping me to try to fix it now.**

---

### header:
seq: 2238
stamp:
secs: 1448269540
nsecs: 681997060
frame_id: ''
status:

```
level: 0
name: TurtleBot Node
message: RUNNING
hardware_id: ''
values: []
```

- level: 0
  name: Operating Mode
  message: Full
  hardware_id: ''
  values: []
- level: 0
  name: Battery
  message: OK
  hardware_id: ''
  values:
  -
  key: Voltage (V)
  value: 15.613
  -
  key: Current (A)
  value: -0.344
  -
  key: Temperature (C)
  value: 32
  -
  key: Charge (Ah)
  value: 2.297
  -
  key: Capacity (Ah)
  value: 2.696
- level: 0
  name: Charging Sources
  message: None
  hardware_id: ''
  values: []
- level: 0
  name: Cliff Sensor
  message: OK
  hardware_id: ''
  values:
  -
  key: Left
  value: False
  -
  key: Left Signal
  value: 2475
  -
  key: Front Left
  value: False
  -
  key: Front Left Signal
  value: 2561
  -
  key: Front Right
  value: False
  -
  key: Front Right Signal
  value: 2606
  -
  key: Right
  value: False
  -
  key: Right Signal
  value: 2609
- level: 0
  name: Wall Sensor
  message: OK
  hardware_id: ''
  values:
  -
  key: Wall
  value: False
  -
  key: Wall Signal
  value: 61
  -
  key: Virtual Wall
  value: False
- level: 2
  name: Gyro Sensor
  message: Gyro Power Problem: For more information visit http://answers.ros.org/question/2091/turtlebot-bad-gyro-calibration-also.
  hardware_id: ''
  values:
  -
  key: Gyro Enabled
  value: True
  -
  key: Raw Gyro Rate
  value: 0
  -
  key: Calibration Offset
  value: 0
  -
  key: Calibration Buffer
  value: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
- level: 0
  name: Digital Outputs
  message: OK
  hardware_id: ''
  values:
  -
  key: Raw Byte
  value: 1
  -
  key: Digital Out 2
  value: ON
  -
  key: Digital Out 1
  value: OFF
  -
  key: Digital Out 0
  value: OFF

---

we see a lot of '0's here. This may be a proble of my gear wheel. I'll try to fix it now.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221362/turtlebot-bad-gyro-calibration/) by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2015-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Remove the power distribution circuit board from your CREATE Base. On a full battery charge, ensure that there is a constant 5V power supply between pins 8 and 14, as shown in the photo.

[image: image description]

If there isn't you'll have to use an external gyro or maybe change the base.

---

Originally posted by [Loneflyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24028/loneflyer/) with karma: 96 on 2015-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2015-11-23**:
I'm using iRobot Create 2 as the base. I see there is an encoder near the wheel. Furthermore, I noticed that "iRobot_Roomba_600_Open_Interface_Spec_0908.pdf" shows us Roomba Open Interface Sensor Packets, and we can read the distance and angle from the encoder. The 'gyro' in your message means that?